# Deleting or updating Datastore properties using Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datastore

If you want to add a property to an existing entity, you just "clone it" and add it.

```
  Entity oldEntity = c.element();
  Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder(oldEntity);
  entityBuilder.addProperty(
          DatastoreHelper.makeProperty("newProperty",
                  DatastoreHelper.makeValue("Value")
          )
  );
  c.output(entityBuilder.build());
```

If you want to update a property, adding it again hoping to overwrite the old value won't work. It won't save to the datastore because a property's name must be unique, and now you'd have two with the same name.

```
Error writing to the Datastore (400): Entity has duplicate property name
```

If you want to remove a property, you need to know the index from the Property List, and for that you'd need to list all the properties, check if the property you want to update exists, keep track of the index number, and then remove it.

Is there a builtin helper for this procedure or a shortcut I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Google Cloud Dataflow's Java SDK uses Datastore API v1beta2 and there's no way to directly add a property to an entity, not even using `DatastoreHelper.getPropertyMap` and adding properties to the resulting `Map<String, Value>` because that method returns an UnmodifiableMap.

When they switch to v1beta3 the properties will be exposed as just a map, [according](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/128#issuecomment-226055803) to a team member.

So this is how I managed it on v1beta2:

```
Entity oldEntity = c.element();

// We need to get the property map, but the one from DatastoreHelper is an unmodifiableMap
Map<String, Value> oldEntity_map = DatastoreHelper.getPropertyMap(oldEntity);
Map<String, Value> newEntity_map = new HashMap<String, Value>();
newEntity_map.putAll(oldEntity_map);

// Adding or updating a property
newEntity_map.put("newProperty", DatastoreHelper.makeValue("Value").build());
// Deleting a property
newEntity_map.remove("delete-this");

Entity.Builder updatedEntity = Entity.newBuilder(oldEntity);
updatedEntity.clear();
updatedEntity.setKey(oldEntity.getKey());

for (Map.Entry<String, Value> property : newEntity_map.entrySet())
{
    updatedEntity.addProperty(
       DatastoreHelper.makeProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue()));
}

c.output(updatedEntity.build());
```

Comment: Does this work if one of the properties is an embedded entity?

Comment: Yes! Are you trying to update it or delete it? Check this question / answer combo to see if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/q/34774351/190908

Comment: The use case is same as yours; i need to be able to add or update(if its already there)  a property to the entity. The problem with the approach you suggested is, the order or properties in the old and new entity is changing. This is not what is required.

Comment: Does the order matter because you rely on the property's index number?

Comment: I'd suggest replacing your probable calls to `getProperty(index)` with the use of `getPropertyMap`and then looking for the property you need by name.